# Google Places API sessiontoken not working

Tags: session, token, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I implemented an autocomplete using the places autocomplete api and places detail api for a React app using Express as the backend. The calls to the apis are from the backend so I'm using the Node.js Client for Google Maps Services found here: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js. My code below is using the same sessiontoken to call the api but google is charging me for every letter I type - basically ignoring my sessiontoken. I checked the code for Node.js Client for Google Maps Services, and I think I'm using sessiontoken correctly as this is the test they use to test their code:

`const params = { input: "Seattle", sessiontoken: "asdf", key: "foo" };`

This is my code, using a sessiontoken generated from the frontend to call the api.

```
console.log('sessiontoken for locaton query', sessionToken)
const result = await client.placeAutocomplete({
            params: {
                input: q,
                language: lang,
                types: '(regions)',
                key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                sessiontoken: sessionToken
            },
            timeout: 1000 // Optional timeout value in milliseconds
        });
```

I can see that I'm sending the same sessiontoken as I am console.logging it:

[sessiontoken log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKf0D.png)

The last line is my call to the places api like this to "end" the request:

```
console.log('session token for the first query', sessionToken)
const resultEN = await client.placeDetails({
            params: {
                place_id: id,
                fields: 'address_component',
                language: 'en',
                sessiontoken: sessionToken,
                key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY
            },
            timeout: 1000 // Optional timeout value in milliseconds
        });
```

Google is not combining all of my requests into 1, and charging me for every request I make. I've searched online for many hours but couldn't find anyone with the same problem. If someone could give me any hints that I may have done something wrong, that would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to generate a new session token every session you do. ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/session-tokens#create-session-tokens. Please see the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/session-tokens#example) to learn more as to how and when a single session starts and ends.

Comment: All of the requests are part of one session because I haven't made a request to the places detail API yet, which I do at the end (second code block). Essentially the user is typing a place e.g. "Water" and it's making 5 different requests, one for each keystroke, and 1 more for calling the places details api at the end, so in total 6. It should be consolidating all of those separate requests into 1 request for billing. Any ideas?

Comment: My bad. I was looking at my API's "total requests" in the google console, which is updated live. I should be looking at the Billing reports by SKU, which is NOT updated live and that was what got me confused. The code above works.

Comment: Great! there's some kind of delay with the billing reports. But with that said, as long as you're having `per-session` in your SKUs instead of `per-request`, you should be fine.